# How to set the gain of 16-bit PCM samples without using floating-point math?

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing, pcm

I have an array of 16-bit PCM samples (for the purpose of this question, let's say that they are signed). I have to apply a value, ranging from 0 to 65535, as the gain (volume control) for the samples, with 65535 being maximum volume (no change), and 0 being no volume (silence).

The easiest solution would be to convert the gain value to a float 0.0 - 1.0, and while iterating on the array, convert the iterated sample to a float as well, then to multiply the two values, and convert the result back to a 16-bit integer, then write that integer back to the array. I feel like that would be **very** inefficient - we would be doing multiple `short` -> `float` -> `short` conversions, floating point math is slower than integer math, and all of this would be magnified as (usually) 44100 PCM samples are equal to 1 second.

Is there a way to do this without floating-point math? I'm fine with inaccuracies, if any come up.

Comment: Use BenchmarkDotNet to discover that integer math is actually *slower* than a floating point multiply and cast.  Division is expensive and not as well optimized in hardware. 
 Only way to go faster is by using SIMD, not worth the trouble when 44100 pcm samples/sec takes less than 0.5% cpu load to convert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the conversions to and from float by using [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). To keep exactly the original samples at maximum volume, it is a bit easier if the volume is a "Q15" value in the range 0 to 32768. To do a fixed-point multiplication:

1. Upcast the volume and 16-bit sample to 32-bit integers.
2. Multiply them as if they were regular integers.
3. Bitshift the product to the right by 15 bits.

In C, something like this

```
// Copyright 2022 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#include <stdint.h>

void adjust_volume(int16_t* samples, int num_samples, uint16_t volume) {
  for (int i = 0; i < num_samples; ++i) {
    samples[i] = (int16_t)(
        (((int32_t)volume) * samples[i]) / (INT32_C(1) << 15));
  }  
}
```